# Gmail API Pull out plain text email body

Tags: python, css, python-3.x, email, gmail-api

I am trying to decode an email sent to me from a specific source. The email is what looks like a CSS box that contains the info i need. When i run this through the function provided by google, I get what appears to be CSS coding and it is not possible for me to extract the information i need, and the content_type() is "text". But if i forward the same email to myself and run the same exact function on it, i get the content_type() as "multipart", and i am able to extract the plain text of the CSS body, and grab the info I need. I think this is because when I forward it to myself it contains plain text at the top (showing the forward info) as well as the CSS body.

So my question is, how can I extract the same plain text I get from the CSS body after I forward the email to myself, without forwarding the email to myself?  Below is the function I am using:

```
def get_message(service, user_id, msg_id):
    try:
        # Makes the connection and GETS the emails in RAW format.
        message = service.users().messages().get(userId=user_id, id=msg_id, format='raw').execute()
        # Changes format from RAW to ASCII
        msg_raw = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(message['raw'].encode('ASCII'))
        # Changes format type again
        msg_str = email.message_from_bytes(msg_raw)
        # This line checks what the content is, if multipart (plaintext and html) or single part
        content_types = msg_str.get_content_maintype()
        print(content_types)
        if content_types == 'multipart':
            # Part1 is plaintext
            part1, part2 = msg_str.get_payload()
            raw_email = part1.get_payload()
            remove_char = ["|", "=20", "=C2=A0"]
            for i in remove_char:
                raw_email = raw_email.replace(i, "")
            raw_email = "".join([s for s in raw_email.strip().splitlines(True) if s.strip()])
            return str(raw_email)
        else:
            return msg_str.get_payload()
    except:
        print('An error has occured during the get_message function.')
```

Comment: What do you mean by `it is not possible for me to extract the information i need`? What are you getting instead? Also, could you provide an example email to reproduce this?

Comment: What i mean is that when I use the function above to pull the email body data, if I am decoding it directly from the source, the content_type() is text, but it returns html/css data. But when i forward the email to myself (which adds plain text to the email) then run it through this same exact function, it sees the plain text and HTML as 2 different parts and I can specify to only return the plain text, and then I can easily extract the info I need. I want to pull the plain text (that is clearly there) without the need to forward the email to myself first.

Comment: Could you please provide what html/css data you are getting when trying to extract the text from the original message?